# How to merge multiple H.264 streams into a single H.264 stream

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, fpga

I encode camera images with several parallel H.264 baseline I-frame only encoder cores in FPGA (more parallel cores are required to get the encoding done fast enough without external memory). I use an opensource [encoder](https://github.com/bcattle/hardh264/). On simulator I use 352x288 yuv420 input image and I slice it to 2 horizontal halves.

The decoder is on another embedded device and I can decode the separated slices correctly. But, instead of several decoded video sequences, I would need to have just one vido sequence (with the whole image) from one H.264 byte stream. It is preferred to merge the H.264 streams on the FPGA (instead of doing this by post processing the decoded slice video sequences on the embedded host).

So, the input image data looks like this:

```
    .--.-----.--.--.-----.--.
    |MB|     |MB|MB|     |MB|
    | 0| ... |10|11| ... |21|
    |--.     '--|--'     '--|
    |MB|        |           |
    |22|        |           |
    |--'        |           |
    |   Slice   |   Slice   |
    |     0     |     1     |
    '-----------'----------'
```

And the encoder's block diagram is this (just one encoder core shown, without merging):

```
                                 YUV420 MacroBlocks (16*16 pixel)
                                         |       |
                                  chroma |       | luma
                                         |       |
                      .----------------.-------. |
                      |                | |     | |
                      |                v v     v v
                 reconstruct      intra8x8cc  intra4x4 ---> header
                      ^                |        |             |
                      |                v        v             |
                inv.transform        coretransform            |
                      ^                |     |                |
                      |                |     v                |
                  dequantise           | dctransform          |
                   ^       ^           |     |                |
                   |       |           v     v                |
        inv.dc.transform <-'---------- quantise               |
                                           |                  |
                                           v                  |
                                         buffer               |
                                           |                  |
                                           v                  |
                                          cavlc               |
                                           |                  |
                                           v                  |
                                         tobytes <------------'
                                           |
                                           v
                                         H.264 byte stream
```

The encoded h264 data from a singel core (parsed with [H264Naked,](https://github.com/shi-yan/H264Naked) see [parse.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kktelcy06jmpa0t/h264naked_ref.txt?dl=0), [ref.yuv420](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqkohwten6qax6z/ref.yuv420?dl=0) and [ref.264](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbon3ul5jimkq60/ref.264?dl=0)) contains 3 NAL-s: in the first one there is a Sequence Parameter Set, in the second a Picture Parameter Set and in the third a Coded slice of an IDR picture. The SPS and PPS headers are static and these are generated on the host. The IDR header is generated by the encoder on the FPGA. Currently I use a constant Quantization Parameter (i.e. VBR, but it is planned to implement CBR, with variable QP later).

To get the encoded streams merged, I have removed the IDR header from the slices (except from slice 0) in the header block. Then I buffer the output of CAVLC blocks from each encoder for a whole MB row (this is the encoded MB data, MB headers can be identified from the output of header block). Then from this buffer I drive all the CAVLC data to a new instance of tobytes block in this sequence:

- CAVLC data of one MB row from slice 0
- CAVLC data of one MB row from slice 1
- the above is repeated till the end of the frame.

When I decode this merged H.264 stream, then I get the following error with ffmpeg (see [merged_tobytes.264](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ic3cms9p40g80od/merged_tobytes.264?dl=0) and [ffplay_error.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hkombdr087z7knf/ffplay_error.txt?dl=0)):

```
[h264 @ 0x7f5f0c00ac00] dquant out of range (-112) at 13 1B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f5f0c00ac00] error while decoding MB 13 1
[h264 @ 0x7f5f0c00ac00] concealing 396 DC, 396 AC, 396 MV errors in I frame
```

With JM reference decoder I get this error ([jm_dec_error.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s42hxmjea5ul3qd/jm_dec_error.txt?dl=0)):

```
mb_qp_delta is out of range (-112)
illegal chroma intra pred mode!
```

I think the problem is that the decoder does not know about the slices and expects neighboring MB data from other slice which are not available in the encoded data. I have checked the Macroblock prediction syntax in the [standard](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.264-202108-I!!PDF-E&type=items) (chapter 7.3.5.1), but I do not see how should I correct this (I have very little knowledge about H.264). On the encoder side, I see that intra4x4 and intra8x8cc are using neighboring MB prediction and pixel data from the top and left MB neighbors when those are available (we have no top MB neighbors in the first MB row and we have no left MB neighbor at first MB of each MB row, in each slice).

I have also tried to use FMO and declared slice groups (slice_group_map_type=2) as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_Macroblock_Ordering), but FMO and slice groups are not supported by typical H.264 decoders (see ffmpeg [issue](https://www.mail-archive.com/ffmpeg-issues@lscube.org/msg03024.html), I think it is used only in broadcast equipments). In fact, I had also got error from JM reference decoder even when I have declared the slice groups (see [merged_tobytes_with_slice_grops.264](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8mnavr5y4dgr469/merged_tobytes_with_slice_grops.264?dl=0) and [jm_dec_slice_groups_error.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgxnup7m19atm5j/jm_dec_slice_groups_error.txt?dl=0)):

```
warning: Intra_8x8_Horizontal prediction mode not allowed at mb 0
illegal chroma intra pred mode!
```

Any help is appreciated.

Reference photo is taken from [here](http://%20https://unsplash.com/photos/NuIbSaztf_g).

PS: if someone can advise a deblocker which could be used with this FPGA core, that would be also nice.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just interleave slice data like that. From a decoder's point of view, each slice is supposed to be a complete and independent decoding unit, so a decoder can parse and decode multiple slices at the same time using different slice decoding instances (e.g. threads).

Slices are also supposed to be contiguous in scan-order. So, in your example, you'd want to cut the image horizontally (in two slices on top of each other) rather than vertically, and then append the second slice after the first - and fixing up the header(s) to signal the correct frame height. This should decode correctly. To do this for more slices, just cut the individual slices smaller. But they should always be contiguous in scan-order.

Comment: I see, thank you. The problem is that I do not have enough buffer for slicing horizontally (I need to start processing the data with all the encoder cores in the first or second MB row, I do not have a frame buffer). If I would have many small horizontal slices (like 2 slice per each row in the whole frame) then I think the compression efficiency would drop dramatically (I will test it!). What would happen if I would force the MB's on my vertical slice boundaries to be I_PCM coded? Or would it work if I would pass the pixel and prediction modes from slice 0 edge MB to slice 1 first MB coders?

Comment: As long as you consider this only for mode selection, not actual bitstream (slice) writing, you can probably get away with doing vertical chopping (thinner columns) and forbidding left-edge usage on each boundary (so PCM for corners, and H or V for left/top boundary blocks). But you'll need a separate process that accumulates selected modes across chunks and writes actual NAL slices.